# Customer login does not work after customer import via CSV (Hash not same)

Tags: magento2, import, password

I successfully exported my customers from Magento 1 into a CSV and then used the import tool in Magento 2 to import them. On the backend everything looks fine and all customers and addresses are listed.

However, if you try to login from the frontend, it says:

```
"Invalid login or password."
```

Looking at the customer csv file I noticed that the password hashes seem to be inconsistent. With some older ones looking like this:

```
4a42437364414ac618c65623a7337639:mZ
```

And newer ones down at the bottom of the csv file look like this:

```
13d82841997285ad391a7a951ec414fe:AzzxM5yPIZaEHfS9kEh2EjZlvcuDzTd5
```

I'm guessing Magento updated their hashing method at some point and this is the result.

Any ideas how to make the older ones compatible with Magento2?

Thanks.

Comment: Whilst the hash length was updated, this is highly unlikely to be the cause of your issue, as the hashing mechanism wasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

When importing hashes into M2, append `:0` on to the end of the hash. M2 sees this and then converts the hash accordingly. I did this to my own account when testing. Now, setting on to do a mass import.